# WPDB foreign key not working

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress and the Wordpress database. I have 3 tables. Two are tables that contain their own Primary Key's and the third is a cross reference table. The problem lies in the cross reference, or xref table.

This xref table has two foreign keys that link to the other two table's Primary Keys. However whenever I insert data into the first two tables, no data shows up in the xref table.

Perhaps my code in creating that xref table is incorrect.

```
$ml_char = $wpdb->prefix . "ml_char";
$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
$sql1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $ml_char . " (
    `char_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`char_id`)
) $charset_collate;";
dbDelta( $sql1 );

$ml_wpid = $wpdb->prefix . "ml_wpid";
$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
$sql2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $ml_wpid . " (
    `wp_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`wp_id`)
) $charset_collate;";
dbDelta( $sql2 );

$ml_wpid_x_char = $wpdb->prefix . "ml_wpid_x_char";
$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
$sql3 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $ml_wpid_x_char . " (
    `char_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
    `wp_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (char_id) REFERENCES wp_ml_char(char_id),
FOREIGN KEY (wp_id) REFERENCES wp_ml_wpid(wp_id)
) $charset_collate;";
dbDelta( $sql3 );
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, that is exactly what is supposed to (not) happen; a foreign key will (just) check if the reference values exist in your 2 other tables if you insert data to the `xref` table, not insert data for you.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. I pictured the xref table displaying the values from the primary keys in the other two tables, but what you're saying it that the xref table with the foreign key will not just display data on it's own.

Comment: No, it will not display data on its own (a table stores data that you have to insert first). You should describe what you want to do. You are maybe looking for `select`, `join` or a `view`. Or something different, it's a little bit hard to guess...